# How to tune the threshold for classification using Leave one out in MLR package?

Tags: r, classification, threshold, rpart, mlr

I am using mlr package in R to train my model.
I wanted to train my model and do prediction. At the moment I use Recursive Partitioning for Classification and the sample is created using Leave one out method.
I want to set the optimum threshold for the prediction.

I have tried using model, and set the threshold value to makeLearner, which did not work as expected.

I tried using MakeParam and tune predict.threshold in Learner, which also did not work properly.

```
library(mlr)

mlr_data <- as.data.frame(scale(dataset_correlation[,1:154]))
mlr_data$label <- factor(dataset_correlation$label)


task <- makeClassifTask(data = mlr_data,target = "label")
lrnr <- makeLearner("classif.randomForest",predict.type = "prob")
rdesc <- makeResampleDesc("LOO")

ps = makeParamSet(
  makeIntegerParam("predict.threshold", lower = 0.1, upper = 1.0)
)

ctrl = makeTuneControlRandom(tune.threshold = TRUE)
lrn2 = makeTuneWrapper(lrnr, par.set = ps, control = ctrl, resampling = rdesc)
r = resample(lrn2, task, rdesc, extract = getTuneResult)
print(r$extract)
```

Error:

> "Error in checkTunerParset(learner, par.set, measures, control) :
>
> Can only tune parameters for which learner parameters exist: predict.threshold"

I need the threshold to be tuned automatically and use that tune value for prediction.

Got the solution:

check this website
https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/08/practicing-machine-learning-techniques-in-r-with-mlr-package/

Comment: Do you mean [classifier calibration](https://mlr.mlr-org.com/articles/tutorial/classifier_calibration.html)?

Comment: No, I want the resampling to be done with a threshold tuned by TuneControlWrapper

Comment: Still not sure if I understand. Something like the plots [here](https://mlr.mlr-org.com/articles/tutorial/performance.html#binary-classification)?

Comment: Can't we tune the threshold like https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr/issues/856#issuecomment-214875911 ??? I want to tune it when I am doing prediction

Comment: You can use `tuneThreshold()` directly.

Comment: I tried using `tuneThreshold()` and tried adding `predict.threshold` in makeLearner to corresponding value. But then the misclassification rate was more. So can you suggest any other method?

Comment: All of the error values you'll get are estimates and you won't get exactly the same on different splits of the data. That's by the very nature of machine learning.

Comment: I got the solution, thanks for your contribution

Comment: Great! Could you post this as an answer to your question please so that other people with similar problems can find it?